# Trying to change certain values in objects while using file access

Tags: python, arrays, object, slice, file-access

I'm trying to change a specific part of an object. Specifically, I'm trying to subtract a certain value from the acc. Where then the change is recorded on an already created text file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 152, in <module>
    start()
  File "main.py", line 141, in start
    withdraw(id,input("How much do you want to withdraw?"))
  File "main.py", line 55, in withdraw
    if allCustom[d].hkid== x:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Customer
```

```
class Customer: 
    def __init__(self, name, date, address, hkid, acc):
        self.name = name
        self.date = date
        self.address = address
        self.hkid = hkid
        self.acc = acc
allCustom = [customer1, customer2, customer3, customer4, customer5]
customer1 = Customer ("Sarah Parker","1/1/2000","Hong Kong, Tai Koo,Tai Koo Shing Block 22,Floor 10, Flat 1", "X1343434","2222")
def withdraw (x,y):
    global allCustom
    count = 0
    for d in allCustom:
        if allCustom[d].hkid== x:
            if int(allCustom[d].acc) >= int(y):
                allCustom[d] = Customer (allCustom[d].name, allCustom[d].date, allCustom[d].address, allCustom[d].hkid, str(int(allCustom[d].acc)-int(y)))
                print("Success! Please collect your money.")
                break
            else:
                print("Sorry but you have inseffecient funds to withdraw $"+y)
        elif count == len(allCustom):
            print("Your HKID does not match any account in our database. Returning to starting screen")
        else:
            count +=1
def UpdateFile():
    global allCustom
    OutFile=open("CustomInfo.txt", "w")
    for c in allCustom:
      OutFile.write(f"\nName:{c.name}\n")
      OutFile.write(f"Birth Date:{c.date}\n")
      OutFile.write(f"Address:{c.address}\n")
      OutFile.write(f"HKID:{c.hkid}\n")
      OutFile.write(f"Account value:{c.acc}\n")
    OutFile.close()
UpdateFile()
```

Comment: what is your problem? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: don't you get error ? Code `for d in allCustom:` should give you object `Customer` in variable `d`, not index to list `allCustom`, so you should use `if d.hkid == x:` instead of `if allCustom[d].hkid == x:`

Comment: I don't see any "file access" in your code. And I don't see you use text file. BTW: if you want to change value in file, then you have to read object to memory, change object in memory and write object back to file. It will NOT change file content when you only change object in memory.

Answer (score 0):

As @furas said in a comment, just use:

```
if d.hkid== x:
```

This is because `for d in allCustom:` will *iterate* over the *list* `allCustom` binding the variable `d` to each item of the list in turn. At this point `d` is a `Customer` object and you can access its attributes. You therefore do not need to try to lookup the customer in the list because you already have a reference to it in `d`.

You will need to correct the other instances of `allCustom[d]` in the rest of your code.

---

You probably have this confused because of this Python idiom:

```
for i in range(len(allCustom)):
    if allCustom[i].hkid== x:
```

which uses indices to access the items in the list. The first form `for d in  allCustom` is preferred - it is clearer and more succinct.